# What is the quality of the non-retina images that Xcode creates from the @2x version?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, retina-display

Since I have been told that Xcode automatically scales down an image to non-retina when I only have the @2x form in my project, it seems unnecessary to create the other image. This made me create my apps without the non-retina images.

But recently I had a discussion about this issue, and was told that the quality of the image (on non-retina devices) won't be as good if I don't separately save a non-retina image.

Is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's true, the quality won't be as good, but it's also not a good idea to just use @2x for a few other reasons.

1. A simple resize of a retina image might not be the best way to keep the semantics of an image. For example, an icon may look great at the right size in @2x, but when reduced in size, it's hard to distinguish what the icon is. A such, your regular sized image might be a slightly different icon, that is lower in resolution but easier to determine its meaning.
2. The image is held in memory when being used. A @2x image is 4x the resolution of a normal image, and as such will take up around x4 the memory. Devices like the iPad 1 and 3GS (that have non-retina displays) have a limited amount of memory, and not much of it spare. As such, the retina images will take up a lot more of the memory available, and your app/device will not perform well.
3. Similar to point 1, but the resizing done for @2x images to fit correctly on a 1x screen is very naive, and does not perform any sampling to make the image look nice. For example, when shrunk down the image may be very aliased and rough. If you had a regular image file, that is derived from the @2x version, you can perform your own sampling and resolution reduction methods, to make sure it looks the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

For our iOS application we have an (overly) obsessive designer who spent a lot of time designing assets independently for retina and non-retina resolutions and I asked him why he spent so much time on each instead of essentially 'down/up scaling'.  He had some excellent points along the lines of **'if you want your assets to look good on both retina and non-retina you need a person to make intelligent decisions about your asset paths/outlines'**.

Take for instance a 57x57 button or icon with a 2px outer border, a 4px white inner border and a shadow.  If you simply scale that up to 114x114 the 'path' or line of those borders are scaled up to 4px and 8px which can cause two problems

- at the new size 4px and 8px may be **too** thick, you need to look at the asset and decide that perhaps 3px and 5px makes more sense
- the anti-aliasing of the corners may no longer look right, they may be too thick or too thin

He showed me what an asset looks like if you just scale it up/down vs him actually spending time finessing it and it was a pretty dramatic difference.  A lot of his points are summed up well in [this article](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina2/)